# How can I track memory allocation of C++ standard library calls?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider this simple example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <numeric>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::list<int> l(10);
    std::iota(l.begin(),l.end(),77);

    std::vector<std::list<int>::iterator> v(l.size());
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), l.begin());

    std::vector<int> dest;
    std::copy_if(l.begin(), l.end(), std::back_inserter(dest), [](int i){return i%2==1;});

    for(auto n : dest)
        std::cout << n << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

When run under Valgrind, it gives me the following output:

```
==27353==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 15 frees, 380 bytes allocated
```

Is it possible to track exactly where those allocs occured (i.e. which data structure performed allocation and when exactly)?

Comment: did you try [massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html)?

Comment: @m.s. I just did but the output was the same.

Comment: you need to run `ms_print massif.out.12345` (number varies) after running `valgrind --tool=massif`

Comment: OK, thanks. The output is hard to read at first but it looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: @REACHUS Try massif-visualizer.

Comment: Solution should go as an answer and be accepted by the author.

Comment: as an alternative to massif you can also try [heaptrack](http://milianw.de/blog/heaptrack-a-heap-memory-profiler-for-linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to track C++ library allocation calls is to use [Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html), a heap profiler tool (part of Valgrind):

1. Run Valgrind with Massif enabled:

   `valgrind --tool=massif`
2. Use `ms_print` to analyze output from Massif:

   `ms_print massif.out.12345 (number varies)`

Answer (score -1):

Try giving valgrind the `--keep-stacktraces=alloc` option. Note using that option will increase the overhead of using valgrind. Here are the docs http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.options so you can fine tune what valgrind captures.